# Apply git hooks in template folder to specific remote repos

Tags: git, hook, githooks

I know that the hooks in the git template folder will be installed in all future repositories that I clone. What I need is to install these hooks automatically when cloning the repositories that come from a specific bitbucket user.

Examples:

- git clone git@bitbucket.org:user-1/project-1.git --> Install hooks
- git clone git@bitbucket.org:user-2/project-2.git --> NO install hooks

Is there a way to achieve that? Is it possible to filter different projects from the same user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, but it requires you to organize your repositories in different directories depending on the different set of git configurations you want to apply.

In your case you could have one directory for all your normal git repositories, and a different one for all the repos from the user you want to single out.

Then you'd use the [`includeIf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) section in `gitconfig` using a recent git version.

You can see a very detailed description of this process [here](https://itnext.io/setup-git-with-multiple-configs-9b4111d6928c), where applying different hooks to each repo is included.